# Cluster, Index and Partition on a single table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, cluster-computing, partitioning

I've looked for a while over Google but can't find the answer!

Can a database table have multiple partitions, indexes **and** clusters attached to it?

Will it bring up an error if a partition is on the same row as an index?

Is there any benefit in this?

Many thanks,
Zulu

Comment: Have you tried it?  It seems a sensible way to validate if something is possible or not...

Comment: I haven't, simply because the database is **huge** and because it is for my dissertation, it will be implemented on a different computer (so screenshots can be taken with my university username). Was just seeing if anyone knew for my piece of mind!

Comment: Create a new table, put some dummy data in that table, index that table, do what you like with it.  You don't need to trial options on live data...

Comment: What do you mean "if a partition is on the same row as an index"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A table can have many indexes, and those are unrelated to whether it is a standard table, a partitioned table, or a clustered table.  (Although if the table is partitioned, you have a choice about whether to create a separate index on each partition or a global index for the whole table.)

A table cannot belong to multiple clusters, since a cluster determines the actual physical storage location of the table.

A table can have multiple partitions (of course, else what would be the point?).  It can't have multiple partitioning schemes, if that's what you mean.

I presume but have not confirmed that clusters and partitions are mutually exclusive, since they would have potentially conflicting effects on how the table data should be organized on disk.

Comment: This is bloody brilliant thank you - Didn't know about table not being able to belong to multiple clusters though, which means I've wasted about an hour today :(

Comment: I'm a little confused actually - you stated that multiple partitions could be set on a table, but this hasn't worked... I've posted the question here if you wouldn't mind taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180514/multiple-partitions-on-a-table

Comment: @Zulu -- that's what I meant by multiple "partitioning schemes", i.e. different methods of determining which partition a particular row belongs in.  You can't have more than one of these, as explained in the answer to your other question.