# Multiple partitions on a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was under the impression that multiple partitions could be placed on a table, so it surprised me when I entered the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentDetails1
(ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
ParentName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR (10) CHECK (Gender IN ('m', 'f')) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ParentDetails_PK PRIMARY KEY (ParentID))
PARTITION BY RANGE (ParentName)
    (partition ParentNamePartition1 VALUES LESS THAN ('B'),
     partition ParentNamePartition2 VALUES LESS THAN ('D'),
     partition ParentNamePartition3 VALUES LESS THAN ('F'),
     partition ParentNamePartition4 VALUES LESS THAN ('H'),
     partition ParentNamePartition5 VALUES LESS THAN ('J'),
     partition ParentNamePartition6 VALUES LESS THAN ('L'),
     partition ParentNamePartition7 VALUES LESS THAN ('N'),
     partition ParentNamePartition8 VALUES LESS THAN ('P'),
     partition ParentNamePartition9 VALUES LESS THAN ('R'),
     partition ParentNamePartition10 VALUES LESS THAN ('T'),
     partition ParentNamePartition11 VALUES LESS THAN ('V'),
     partition ParentNamePartition12 VALUES LESS THAN ('X'),
     partition ParentNamePartition13 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))
PARTITION BY HASH (ParentID)
    partitions 10
PARTITION BY LIST (Gender)
    (partition ParentGenderPartition1 VALUES ('m'),
     partition ParentGenderPartition2 VALUES ('f'))
CLUSTER
    ParentContact_Cluster (ParentID);
```

...and got the error stating that only one partition clause could be entered on a table?!

Is there a work around for this?

Many thanks,
Zulu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are limited to one partitioning scheme for a table.  That partitioning scheme could include both partitions and subpartitions depending on the problem you are trying to solve.

What would it even mean to have multiple competing partitioning schemes on a single table?

Comment: I'm a beginner at database optimisation so not sure how everything works just yet. I thought that it would be possible to add partitions to differing columns to aid in faster querying, but I guess I will do some reading up on subpartitions. Many thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subpartitioning to do what you want to do.  [Oracle 11.2 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#VLDBG1106)